# Comparing multiple $\tt armax$ models

Tags: matlab, system-identification

I would like to create an algorithm that, given an `iddata`,  estimates different `armax` models with different `na`, `nb`, `nc`, `nk`, and finally show the compare plot.

I know how to use the `armax` estimation function, but how can I store the model in a variable in a such that I can compare them later?

Comment: You can perform a n-grid search and create multiple models. for na=2:8 for nb=2:8 for nc=1:4 sys[na,nb,nc]=armax(na,nb,nc) end end end Inside the same loop you can include the performance metrics that you desire. As a rule of thumb you need 2 poles for each spectral peak. MA models perform better for "smoother" spectra.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just doing `sys = armax(data,[na,nb,nc,nk]);` [as per the Mathworks manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/armax.html)? sys is the variable. You could do sys[i] = ... to store several of them in an array (or perhaps sys{i}).

Then, to compare them, you could use [`getcov()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/getcov.html) and compare the covariances of each model.  These covariances tell you how "uncertain" the model is.

Another approach might be to look at the [model residuals](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/residual-analysis.html). If the residuals are white (uncorrelated), then the model is good.  The relatively energy / power of the residuals will be a measure of how accurate the model matches the data (the smaller the residual, the better the model).